# What is correct mud ring size for ceramic tile?

Tags: electrical, tile, junction-box

With a square box installed flush with studs, 5/8 cement board and ceramic tile if I want the mud ring perfectly flush, should I use a 3/4 inch one?

Comment: Wouldn't that depend a lot (OK, entirely) on the thickness of the tile you're using and the required mastic notch size?

Comment: @FreeMan yes.  I contemplated posing the question in the form of a matrix :)  Or just assuming it's more of a black art.  But I thought I'd try just asking and see if there's any good advice.

Comment: TBH, I don't see how there's any way of anyone answering this without knowing the thickness of the tile. _However_, I'm most certainly not the world's foremost expert on mud rings nor tile, so I'll just grab the popcorn (actually eggs & bacon - it's breakfast time!) and see what comes up.

Comment: Well, the answer may be "you have to mock it up and measure it with your tile and your trowel and your backer board".  We'll see.  TBH right back, I'm happy to be at a point where I'm thinking about these things rather than just installing whatever jbox I have left over in the garage and realizing later what a mess I've made.

Comment: 1/8" is pretty thin for most tile plus thinset or (shudder) mastic. But, given it's non-comustible, not precisely flush is acceptable to the NEC - how you feel about it may differ, depending on personal perfectionism.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I must admit that after spending a whole week repairing a wall, trying to make it all smooth and level and beautiful, it drives me absolutely NUTS if one corner of a wall plate won't sit flush on the wall!     But also I noticed recently that imperfectly installed switches and outlets are more likely to break or to cause their wall plates to break especially in response to rough treatment.  Spacers can compensate but still ... I'd like to *try* to get it right.

Comment: You DO NOT want the ring perfectly flush a slight recess is much better because you don’t want the occasional tile variation to allow the cover plate to leave a gap.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer "no" to the part of my question that suggests a 3/4 inch raise.

Here is a 5/8" backer and 5/16" tile (fairly common) with a 1 inch ring.     Either this or a 1-1/4 inch ring would be the right size depending on the thinset thickness (here there is none) and the tile thickness.

[image]